# Sequelize : upgrading from v4 to v5 gives error : Cannot read property 'field' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have been using sequelize version 4.44.3 in my project. Since there was an issue with using **separate** ([link](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9748)), I just tried to upgrade to v5. After installing the new version, I immediately got this error:

```
/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/has-many.js:138
    this.sourceKeyField = this.source.rawAttributes[this.sourceKey].field || this.sourceKey;
                                                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'field' of undefined
    at HasMany._injectAttributes (/home/nikhil/project/halo/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/has-many.js:138:69)
    at Function.hasMany (/home/nikhil/project/halo/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/mixin.js:37:17)
    at Function.BusinessJobPosition.associate (/app/db/models/businessjobposition.js:37:29)
    at Object.keys.forEach.modelName (/halo/app/db/models/index.js:32:23)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/db/models/index.js:30:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
```

My models will look like this :

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const label = sequelize.define(
        'Label',
        {
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
                allowNull: true,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
            },
            name: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
                allowNull: true,
            },
        },
        {
            timestamps: true,
            paranoid: true

        },
    );
    label.associate = (models) => {
        label.belongsTo(models.Member);
    };
    return label;
};
```

I didnt find any useful information [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/upgrade-to-v5.html)

Comment: Did you solve your problem? How?